# Jquery change event to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way i can basically do this ?

```
 var a= $(".object-type").change(function() 
 {
    //somecode
 }
```

and then call a(); in another function like

```
$("#selectAll").change(function () {
                    if($(this).attr("checked"))
                    {
                        a();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      //some code
                    }
```

Comment: no, but you could do `a.trigger('change');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this way

```
$(".object-type").change(function() 
 {
    //somecode
 });


 $("#selectAll").change(function () {
   if(this.checked)
    {
         $(".object-type").trigger('change'); //Trigger the change event of a different element.
        // or just $(".object-type").change();
   //some code
 });
```

A sample [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5bRKH/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a= function() 
 {
    //somecode
 }

$(".object-type").change(a);

$("#selectAll").change(function () {
                    if($(this).attr("checked"))
                    {
                        a();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      //some code
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to simulate the `change` event of `$(".object-type")`, why cant you just try the [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) events provided by jQuery.

```
$("#selectAll").change(function () {
 if($(this).prop("checked"))
 {
     $(".object-type").trigger("change");
     //you could also use this 
     $(".object-type").change();
 }
 else
 {
    //some code
 } });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking here.  If you want two different jquery triggers to utilize the same functionality then you want to extract the callback function from the jquery trigger:

```
var a = function(event){//do something};
$('.class1').change(a);
$('.class2').change(a);
```

when class1 or class2 are changed the same function will be called.

If what you want if for one jquery trigger to execute another one then you can litterally `trigger` it:

```
$('.class1').change(function(event){//do something});
$('.class2').change(function(event){
    $('.class1').trigger('change');
    // do something else
});
```